# Make StackLayout transparent so the WebView behind can be seen

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I am using Visual Studio 2017, the project is a cross-platform Xamarin Forms mobile app, version 4.0

I would like to add a transparent StackLayout (Footer) that contains a non transparent button on top of a StackLayout that contains a webview.

I am trying to achieve this:

[image: transparent StackLayout (Footer)]

As you can see the bottom StackLayout (Footer) has an opacity of 0.9 and the WebView behind can still be seen.

I have tried this way:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="WebView" TargetType="{x:Type WebView}">
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Fill"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="1000"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="1000"></Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="Footer" TargetType="{x:Type StackLayout}">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{x:StaticResource BlackColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="End"/>
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"></Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="AcceptButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{x:StaticResource YellowColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{x:StaticResource BlackColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="125" />
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="15" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <WebView Style="{StaticResource WebView}" Source="{Binding Url}"></WebView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Style="{StaticResource Footer}">
                <Button Text="{x:Static resources:AppLocalization.Term_Accept}" Style="{StaticResource AcceptButton}"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

But the Footer is all black and the WebView behind cannot be seen.
You guys have any ideas on how to handle this? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to overlay items, so it would be better to use a Grid

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <WebView Style="{StaticResource WebView}" Source="{Binding Url}"></WebView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="End" Style="{StaticResource Footer}">
                <Button Text="{x:Static resources:AppLocalization.Term_Accept}" Style="{StaticResource AcceptButton}"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: This is working, but the Accept button is transparent also, the text can be seen through it, is there a way to make it not transparent? Thank you!

Comment: Well that is related to your Style of the button (which I don't know how it is). Don't forget to mark asnwer as correct :)

Comment: The style of the button is in the description "AcceptButton", I have tried setting the opacity to 1, but is it not working. Do you have any suggestion on this? Thank you!

Comment: Oh I see. Well the solution is to remove the Opacity from the StackLayout, and rather apply it with HEX Color, because the opacity in the parent layout will apply to the children as well. Check https://gist.github.com/lopspower/03fb1cc0ac9f32ef38f4

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!